# How do I assign multiple user subset of test suite in azure devops automatically, instead of manually selected each tester in regression testing

Tags: azure-devops

[image] I have to manually assign test cases subset to each tester I want a way to automatically assign subset of test suite to multiple user and there must be multiple test subsets.

Sorry for my poor knowledge I have just migrated to devops

As you can see there are 3000+ test cases it is inefficient for me to assign them to a single person so i need randomly assign 100-200 test cases to a user.

Is there any other way on Azure Devops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the option: **Assign testers to run all tests**.

[image]

You can input the target user list, then the users will be assigned to the test points.

[image]

Here is a doc about [Assign testers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops#assign-testers)

Comment: thanks for the response I think it still doesn't answer my question I have added an image and also added a description. I think it will clear the scenario.